# Downlading application, it jumps randomly a file during the process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I'm developing an c# patcher, which has the role of comparing the client's and the server's files and if there are some inconsistencies, it automatically downloads them.
It is a WPF application and for handling the multiple async download while updating the progress bar I have used the net 4.5 async/await.
It works perfectly, but now I have the need of making the same application run on windows xp and I decided to refactor all the code using the BackgroundWorker which is disponible also in net 4, the last one supported by xp.

The problem is that a file(a specific one), at the beginning was not downloading.
 When there were like 3 different files do download, if the problematic file was for example the second, after the first, the download started, but it almost instantly jumped to the third one, leaving the second with 0KB of size.
If the problematic file was the first or the last, the result was the same. It was like the program didn't like it.
After some changes, which has not worked, I decided to roll back all the stuff I have done, returning to the initial code.
Well now I have no problems, all the files are downloading correctly, but the fun thing is that if I give the same executable to another person, he has still the same problem I had.
I don't know how it is possible, this file is exactly as the others.

Some other info of the software:
At the start, the program check if all the files are the same, comparing the MD5 hash of each of them with an file with all the MD5 hashes of the updated files(generated before with a php script).
Now if there are some files to download, the program inject into the window the files and the last inject them to the HTTPDownloader(if there are any).
The HTTPDownload start downloading all the files using a for loop, whiling for client.isBusy for making sure that no parallel I/O operations are done.
There is a DownloadListener, which listen all the WebClient events and some customs. It updates the progress bars, the status textblocks etc. using the Dispatcher, because the events will be fired in another thread(by HTTPDownloader).
The stuff happens after is not important for this specific question.

These are the interested files:

window.xaml.cs

```
public void repairButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    repairButton.IsEnabled = false;
    startButton.IsEnabled = false;
    currentFile.Text = "Hashing files...";
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (object s, DoWorkEventArgs es) =>
    {
        scanner.search();
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs ev) =>
     {
         toUpdateFiles = scanner.getToUpdateFiles();
         if (toUpdateFiles != null && toUpdateFiles.Count > 0)
         {
             _startDownload();
         }
         else
         {
             currentFile.Text = "";
             System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(this, "Your client is OK!", "Patcher");
             startButton.IsEnabled = true;

         }
     };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

}
```

This is a click event handler, no problems on this one, but it invoke the _startDownload method.

window.xaml.cs

```
void _startDownload()
{
    HTTPDownloader downloader = new HTTPDownloader(toUpdateFiles, client,"source/");
    DownloadListener listener = new DownloadListener(this, downloader);
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (object s, DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
    {

        downloader.startDownload();
    };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The `HTTPDownloader` is a wrapper of `WebClient`
The `DownloadListener` is a listener which listen all the `WebClient`'s download events(and some customs)
The `BackgroundWorker` runs the `HTTPDownloader.startDownload()` method

HTTPDownloader.cs

```
public void startDownload()
{
    if (Progress != null) client.DownloadProgressChanged += Progress;
    if (Completed != null) client.DownloadFileCompleted += Completed;

    if (client.BaseAddress.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("BaseAddress missing in the WebClient Object");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        PatchFile file = files[i];
        setCurrentIndex(i + 1);
        OnNewFile(file);
        setCurrentFile(file);
        string path = Path.Combine(file.getBasePath(), file.getName());
        string downloadPath = basePath + path;

        if (file.basePath != String.Empty) Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(new Uri(client.BaseAddress), downloadPath), path);
        while (client.IsBusy)
        {
        }
        OnAfterNewFile(file);


    }
    OnAllFileDownloaded();
}
```

Here we are, this is the most important method.
It downloads all the files, raise some events.
(An offtopic question: is `while(client.isBusy)` a good way to wait until a download is finished for starting the other one?(For not raising the I/O WebClient Exception))

Please help me, I'm so tilted. It makes no sense that the same executable runs in another way on my and some else computer.
Maybe threads are managed in different ways, I don't know, I'm pretty new to application programming(So don't blame me if my window.xaml.cs has some business logic and I use an incommon way to handle the ui(DownloadListener), when I saw the MVVC pattern it was late).

 Thanks

Comment: `while(client.isBusy)` is bad. It makes one of the CPU cores busy. Use `DownloadFile`. You are already on non-UI thread with `BackgroundWorker`. Use try/catch to catch an exception and log it

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, it was the hosting which had problems with that file